# Kibana 5.2.0 on EC2: Running in Background

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kibana

I'm running Kibana 5.2.0 on an Amazon Linux AMI by doing `./bin/kibana`. But then I cannot exit the EC2 instance without stopping Kibana. I want to run Kibana in the background so that I can exit the instance without the process stopping. `sudo service kibana start` does not work; I get an error stating, "kibana: unrecognized service."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to run it in the background. You have to add a kibana service before you can start it.

For a quick fix:

```
$ nohup ./bin/kibana &
```

or

```
$ ./bin/kibana &
$ disown
```